# SELECT DISTINCT em coluna do tipo JSON no postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tenho uma tabela que possui 2 colunas, **id** (int auto_increment) e **resp** (json).

Nessa tabela eu tenho valores duplicados na coluna **resp**, algo assim:

> ```
> id | resp
> --------------------------------------------
> 1  | {"nome": "Jonh Doe", "idade": 20} 
> 2  | {"nome": "Jonh Doe", "idade": 20}
> 3  | {"nome": "Maria Claire", "idade": 38} 
> 4  | {"nome": "James Connor", "idade": 50}
> ```

Eu precisaria apenas fazer um famoso e tradicional `SELECT DISTINCT resp FROM tabela`, porém por conta da coluna `resp` ser do tipo **JSON**, não consigo fazer o DISTINCT, o PostgreSQL retorna a seguinte mensagem:

```
ERROR:  could not identify an equality operator for type json
```

Já pesquisei algumas soluções e tentei as seguintes, porém não funcionaram:

**Tentativa 1:**

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT field
FROM (
  SELECT jsonb_object_keys(resp) AS field
  FROM public.tabela
    ) AS subquery
--------------
ERROR: function jsonb_object_keys(json) does not exist
```

**Tentativa 2:**

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT field
FROM (
  SELECT jsonb_array_elements(resp) AS field
  FROM public.tabela
    ) AS subquery
--------------
ERROR: function jsonb_array_elements(json) does not exist
```

**Tentativa 3:**

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT field
FROM (
  SELECT json_array_elements(resp) AS field
  FROM public.tabela
    ) AS subquery
--------------
ERROR: could not identify an equality operator for type json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No *postgresql* você pode SIM agrupar por colunas do *json*, você precisa apenas especificar as colunas que devem servir para agrupamento. [Neste post (en)](http://clarkdave.net/2013/06/what-can-you-do-with-postgresql-and-json/) dá pra ver como; sua consulta ficaria assim:

```
select val->>'nome' as field, val->>'idade' as age, count(*) as total 
from tabelateste 
group by val->>'nome', val->>'idade'
```

[Olha aqui](https://rextester.com/HFLQX50878) um *fiddle* funcionando.

Comment: Realmente funcionou @rLinhares, mas e se por ventura eu não tiver os mesmo itens no JSON? Existe JSON que possuem 5 itens e outros que possuem 20 itens. Exemplo: "nome, idade, sexo, dataNascimento, rg, cpf" e outros JSON que possuem apenas "nome, idade"

Comment: de qualquer forma você vai especificar os campos.. se bastam `nome` e `idade`, ele vai comparar só por eles.. se não existem, acredito que devem ser considerados como diferentes, que o que acontece em comparações que não existe (pra testar é só ir lá no _fiddle_ e deletar a idade de um "Jonh Doe", por exemplo);

Comment: @D.Watson deu certo? conseguiu resolver??

Comment: fiz um teste com alguns campos e até então funcionou, logo menos eu vou tentar fazer com todos os campos possíveis do JSON e retorno aqui com uma resposta. Agradeço sua disponibilidade em me auxiliar.

Comment: @D.Watson algum retorno? o ideal é que a pergunta não fique sem resposta (aceita). Se precisar de alguma melhoria, dá um _alô_..

Comment: Olá @rLinhares peço desculpas por não responder antes. Eu precisei fazer do seguinte modo: Criei um `SELECT` com um `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()` e particionei por umas 15 colunas obrigatórias, ai com isso eu conseguiria identificar os casos distintos dos repetidos, sabendo quais são (No caso, seria os casos com ROW_NUMBER = 1) eu inseri esses em uma outra tabela auxilar, dropei a principal e criei novamente e voltei os dados pra principal. Desse modo eu consegui filtrar apenas os distintos. 
Mas para o ROW_NUMBER() eu precisei indicar coluna por coluna conforme você colocou na resposta.